# The purpose of anonymous function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, anonymous-function

I am learning javascript and I can't understand what is the purpose of anonymous function in JS, **Why we use them ?** 
I found in many tutorials that anonymous function is used to hide local variable.
 I am learning from MDN : and they said :

> "a way of "hiding" some local variables — like block scope in C"

Can explain me this please ?

Comment: I don't see the connection between the question title and the contents.

Comment: I think the title is referring to the book "javascript: the good parts"

Comment: no i am sorry it's a mistake i have just edited the title

Answer (score 0):

You say anonymous functions can hide local variables. By introducing an anonymous function, you can declare variables within it that are not accessible from outside. This is an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
var x = 5;

(function() {
    var y = 3;

    // x and y are visible  
    console.log(x);
    console.log(y);
})();

// Only x is visible
console.log(x);
//console.log(y); // y is undefined
```

There are other uses of anonymous functions. For example, when registering event handlers or calling a function with a callback like:

```
([1, 2, 3]).forEach(function(x) { console.log(x) });
```

Comment: if it is not an anonymouse function, you also can reatch only the x!